# How do I preserve legibility when overlaying text on images?

Tags: print-design, page-layout, layers

I have lots of creative images that I want to use, except when I put text over them it makes the text really hard to read. Other than a drop shadow, is there another way to make it more clear?

Comment: note that many times, for print at least, the text is far more legible in the final product than on screen. Enhancement may not always be needed.

Comment: What program are you working in, what size of text do you use, and what color mode do you have enabled (RBG, or CMYK)?

Comment: You could also add a contrasting border around the outside of each letter.  In Fireworks for instance, convert the text to a path, and give each new "letter_as_shape" a stroke width and colour, rather than just a fill colour.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. Do one or more of these:

- Use larger text
- Use a bolder or simpler typeface
- Use a spot colour, varnish, foil or clear laminate for the text
- Increase the tonal contrast:

  - If your text is black, make it rich black and/or slightly lighten the darkest areas of the image
  - If your text is reversed out (white paper), slightly darken the lightest areas of the image, make sure they are not also pure white
- Blur the image, recrop or rescale it to reduce the amount of competing detail (for example, you'll have issues if there are lots of repeating elements the same size as text stems)
- Convert the background to greyscale, use coloured text
- Colourise the background (monotone or duotone) and use black or reversed-out text
- If none of these work, or aren't practical, find another layout that separates the text from the image.

Answer (score 1):

you could try adding a shape behind the text but in front of the image and adjust the opacity level on the shape until you are happy with the image visibility and the text legibility.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In addition to e100 great answer, using shadows with blur on text may be a good trick.

Comment: could you provide any screenshot to explain the idea, please?